# Calling Javascript variable inside javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
dt.ajax.url( 'test.php?status=' ).load();
```

I defined a variable

```
var status= 55
```

I wand to add `status_2` in the link like this

```
dt.ajax.url( 'test.php?status=&status' ).load();
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You need to `concatenate` the variable with `url`

```
dt.ajax.url('test.php?status='+status).load();
```

Comment: I did not worked with me, thanks but do you have other solustion

Comment: Try to remove `&` and try.

Comment: Your solution is working now, However i found the real issue 

{
text: 'status',
action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
var status= 2;
}
 }

The issue is my current variable are inside function, how could I make it global to reach to the link

Comment: You can declare it just after `script` tag to make global.

Comment: Is it possible that I cal it inside the function ?